# prolog - subsequence of array - each result exactly once

Tags: list, prolog

Here, you can see my implementation:

```
subsequence([], _).   
subsequence([H1|T1], [H1|T2]) :- subsequence(T1, T2).
subsequence(L1, [_|T2]) :- subsequence(L1, T2).
```

For example,

```
?- subsequence(X, [1,2]).
X = [] ;
X = [1] ;
X = [1, 2] ;
X = [1] ;
X = [] ;
X = [2] ;
X = [] ;
```

This result is generally ok, however I would like to get something like that:

```
39 ?- subsequence(X, [1,2]).
X = [] ;
X = [1] ;
X = [1, 2] ;
X = [2] ;
```

(order doesn't matter)
As you can see my aim is eleminate duplicates.  How to do it ?  I tried to anaylyse tree of computation - I did managed to reonstruct this resutlt. However, I can't still eleminate duplicates.  (this tree didn't help me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are repeated solutions due to the clauses of `subsequence/2` not being mutually exclusive when the first argument is `[]`. There are multiple ways that `subsequence([], X)` can succeed. It matches, or succeeds through, both the first and the third clauses of your predicate.

You can modify the third clause to avoid the case where `[]` is the first argument, making the clauses mutually exclusive in that case:

```
subsequence([], _).   
subsequence([X|T1], [X|T2]) :- subsequence(T1, T2).
subsequence([X|T1], [_|T2]) :- subsequence([X|T1], T2).
```

Which will then yield:

```
| ?- subsequence(X, [1,2]).

X = [] ? a

X = [1]

X = [1,2]

X = [2]

no
| ?-
```

---

Another way to accomplish the above would be to define the *third* predicate clause (keeping the first two above) as:

```
subsequence(L, [_|T]) :-
    L = [_|_],    % L is a list with at least one element
    subsequence(L, T).
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However, you another way seems to be curious, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @HaskellFun the "another way" is a substitute only for the 3rd clause of `subsequence/2` as I stated. You still need the first two clauses. When I ran it, it works fine. Make sure you include *all three* clauses for `subsequence/2`. In other words, you still also need `subsequence([], _).` and `subsequence([X|T1], [X|T2]) :- subsequence(T1, T2).` as the first two clauses.

Comment: Yeah. Simply, you in more elegant way check if list is empty. Am I ok ?

Comment: @HaskellFun either way is fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the first clause should suffice. The subsequence of [] should be [], not "anything".

```
subsequence([], []).   
subsequence([H1|T1], [H1|T2]) :- subsequence(T1, T2).
subsequence(L1, [_|T2]) :- subsequence(L1, T2).
```